# Chef + Vagrant + encrypted data bags + Windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra, databags

I'm trying to use Vagrant and Chef to test encrypted data bags. I've created an encrypted data bag using

`knife solo data bag create test test_service --data-bag-path ../../data_bags/ --secret-file ~/.chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret`

and verified the items were created.

Added data_bag and encrypt key path to my Vagrant file

`config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.log_level = :debug
    chef.data_bags_path = "../../data_bags"
    chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path = '~/.chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret'`

The recipe contains

`secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("C:\\tmp\\vagrant-chef-3\\encrypted_data_bag_secret_key")
usr_creds = chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("test","test_service", secret_key)`

When Vagrant runs it loads the encrypted key

`==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Uploading chef encrypted data bag secret key...`

but throws an error

### ArgumentError

You must supply a name when declaring a chef resource

On the Vagrant box I can see that Vagrant creates 2 directories

`C:\tmp\vagrant-chef-3\chef-solo-1\cookbooks
C:\tmp\vagrant-chef-3\chef-solo-2\data_bags`

Within the solo.rb on the Vagrant box `C:\tmp\vagrant-chef-3\solo.rb` there is a setting for cookbooks and the encryption key but not for the location of the data bags

Through some trial and error it looks like Chef cannot find the location of the data bag. Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: Found the first error: chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("test","test_service", secret_key) 'chef' needs to be capitalized.

Now I get the error: 

Data Bag Items must contain a Hash or Mash!

Comment: I've verified that the name of the .json file and id: are the same

Comment: I have now started getting this issue with both solo and zero. The data bag and item are in the file system and are mapped correctly but it cannot find the data bag item during a chef run.

Comment: Just to update my issue in the above comment was due to this error, where vagrant was calling chef-solo rather than zero https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5619

Comment: ping, @SmudgerDan or Garry, did you get the chef solo vagrant working with encrypted data bags? I found a 2yr old repo to help ; 1.[] ; ; ; ; ; X.Knife-solo data bag by thbishop ; ; http://thbishop.com/knife-solo_data_bag/